# Magento 2 guest checkout - shipping first name last name pre-filled randomly - how to make it blank

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have the problem that the fields first name and last name of guest checkout are populated already with data which is not the clients data. How can I set that it is blank? Does anyone have an idea why the fields first name and last name are pre-filled on the first hand? Using Magento 2.3.3
Thank you very much already.

Comment: can you check my answer

Comment: Hi Rakesh. Checking with our agency and let you know. Thank you much.

Comment: Hey Ben - I'm having the exact same thing happen, it's very strange. Did this solve it for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try Below way:

> app/code/Vendor/CheckoutStep/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="Vendor_checkout_layout_processor_t" type="Vendor\CheckoutStep\Plugin\Block\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/CheckoutStep/Plugin/Block/LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\CheckoutStep\Plugin\Block;


class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['firstname']['value'] = '';

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['lastname']['value'] = '';

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320356/magento-2-hide-first-name-and-last-name-field-on-checkout-page